# Tutorial: Simple WCF XML-RPC client

Tags: c#, wcf, client, xml-rpc

**Update: I have provided complete code example in answer below.**

I have built my own little custom XML-RPC server, and since I'd like to keep things simple, on both server and client side, what I would like to accomplish is to create a simplest possible client (in C# preferably) using WCF.

Let's say that Contract for service exposed via XML-RPC is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract
{
    [OperationContract(Action="Ping")]
    string Ping(); // server returns back string "Pong"

    [OperationContract(Action="Echo")]
    string Echo(string message); // server echoes back whatever message is
}
```

So, there are two example methods, one without any arguments, and another with simple string argument, both returning strings (just for sake of example). Service is exposed via http.

Aaand, what's next? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inspired by Doobi's answer, I looked up some more info (examples) on the subject, and came up with the following findings.

Steps to create simple WCF XML-RPC client:

1. Download XML-RPC for WCF from this page: http://vasters.com/clemensv/PermaLink,guid,679ca50b-c907-4831-81c4-369ef7b85839.aspx (download link is at the top of page)
2. Create an empty project which targets **.NET 4.0 Full** framework (or else System.ServiceModel.Web won't be available later on)
3. Add **Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc** project from the archive to your project
4. Add reference to Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc project
5. Add references to System.ServiceModel and System.ServiceModel.Web

**Example code**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{


    // describe your service's interface here
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceContract
    {
        [OperationContract(Action="Hello")]
        string Hello(string name);
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChannelFactory<IServiceContract> cf = new ChannelFactory<IServiceContract>(
                new WebHttpBinding(), "http://www.example.com/xmlrpc");

            cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new XmlRpcEndpointBehavior());

            IServiceContract client = cf.CreateChannel();

            // you can now call methods from your remote service
            string answer = client.Hello("World");
        }
    }
}
```

**Example request/response messages**

*Request XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodCall> 
    <methodName>Hello</methodName> 
    <params> 
        <param> 
            <value> 
                <string>World</string> 
            </value> 
        </param> 
    </params> 
</methodCall>
```

*Response XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodResponse> 
    <params> 
        <param> 
            <value> 
                <string>Hello, World!</string> 
            </value> 
        </param> 
    </params> 
</methodResponse>
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use a WCF channelfactory

```
    IStuffService client = new ChannelFactory<IStuffService>(
        new BasicHttpBinding(),
        *"Stick service URL here"*)
        .CreateChannel();
```

And execute the request by simply calling

```
var response = client.YourOperation(params)
```

More details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx

edit:edited ;)

Comment: +1 for Short and to the point. But it didn't work for me. I was getting "Unrecognized message version" error. See my answer for solution that did work for me.

Comment: please edit your post so i can upvote you (something went wrong, it says that i can upvote you only if you edit your post, hehe)