# Neet a simple example about Multi client - server in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using C# to develop my application for exercises!

I want to use 1 server and 2 clients that connect to the server!

For ex

```
client 1: connect and send a string to the server - server recive that string and  say reply
```

```
client 2: work as client 1
```

i want its using RPC

// sr about my English, i'm a vietnamese

Comment: RPC is a too broad term. Take a look at the [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) (if it's the exercise you're looking for) or [WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878447/tutorial-simple-wcf-xml-rpc-client) (which is a little easier to start on).

Comment: We do not do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server-programming.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nanujogi/chat_server11282005233459PM/chat_server.aspx

Google is your friend.

Comment: Ok,now i'm using WCF to create a sample chat Application on Windows Phone :)

thank you guys !