# RPC using C# for an intermediate level programmer

Tags: c#, rpc

I am trying to implement RPC using C# and was looking around for examples but couldn't find even a hello world example(similar to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html)

JAVA seems to be the popular choice but since I have some experience coding in C# (none in JAVA) thought about trying it out in C#.

Can someone please provide some pointers on how to start socket/rpc programming in C#.

Comment: WebServices, .Net Remoting, WCF

Comment: RPC is a *very* low-level protocol, it requires writing native code, typically in C.  Odds of getting it working in managed code are very low.  There's just no point, exact equivalents are well supported in .NET

Comment: Agree with Hans, the same features are available with the solutions in the @L.B comment.

Comment: Hans - Can you please mention the equivalents that are supported in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

This link is a bit old but should give you the basic idea's.  I found it usual a year or so ago.
[Introduction to RPC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4837/Introduction-to-RPC-Part-1)  The example is writtien in C++ but you should be able to rewrite it to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878447/tutorial-simple-wcf-xml-rpc-client) using WCF. In the end WCF is more flexible and is not just limited to XML, but you can do JSON and SOAP to inter operate with other paltforms. And using the Visual Studio standard project templates, its a no brainer.